# Confusing Sonar error

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar shows that I have the bug
`A "List<String>" cannot contain a "T"`.
The error description is

> Inappropriate "Collection" calls should not be made
>
> See CERT, EXP04-J. - Do not pass arguments to certain Java Collections Framework methods that are a different type than the collection parameter type

Here is the code:

```
List<String> TRUE_VALUES = Arrays.asList("TRUE", "T", "YES", "Y");
```

Here is the test I use to determine if a String value is a true value:

```
TRUE_VALUES.contains(value)
```

Why does Sonar flag this as an error?

Comment: What's the type of `value`?

Comment: What's the version of SonarJava used.

Comment: Sonar version `Version 6.5 (build 27846)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots to consider here. Who defines your sonar rules? Are you getting this Sonar violation while building your code using a SonarQube server with its own custom ruleset? Are you using SonarLint (an eclipse plugin) with its own pre-defined ruleset? If your not sure about the rule itself you could always try to determine where its coming from and see if you want to actually follow that rule, I've come across some situations like this at my current position before and we modified our ruleset to get past some rules that didn't really apply to our project, just something to think about...

Now as far as your code goes, based on your naming convention, "TRUE_VALUES", I'm surprised sonar didn't complain more about it, is this a final field and your not showing it? If yes, you could consider just using a simple string array instead of a Collection to store these string values. If my assumption is correct and your using a Collection to store a static list, it kind of defeats the purpose of using a Collection, why not just use a String array and leave it like below?

```
final String[] TRUE_VALUES = {"TRUE", "T", "YES", "Y"};
```

Comment: It's Sonar server. Yes, it's `static final` value set, using simple array defined I would need to wrap it in stream or asList everytime I need to check if it contains passed value.

Comment: Changing it to simple array and wrapping it in stream when checking, passed Sonar without errors. Just wondering if its the best way to do this...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by wrapping it in a stream, but you could just write a simple for loop to iterate and compare the string values in the array or something like that. If you dig into the ArrayList implementation of contains, you will see it does something kind of like that.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I recommend looking into SonarLint, its an eclipse plugin that you can "hook" to your sonar server and get real time sonar complaints right inside your IDE, this will help you to avoid any sonar violations before even delivering your code. I use it and its tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because, `Arrays.asList` takes in a Generic Type.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

May be the type `String` is not recognized when you say `Arrays.asList("TRUE", "T", "YES", "Y")`.

Can you try this?

```
String strArray[] = new String[]{"TRUE", "T", "YES", "Y"};
List strList = Arrays.asList(strArray);
List<String> TRUE_VALUES = Arrays.asList(strList );
```